# searching for tags and showing all

Tags: mysql, tags

I have 3 tables to create a tagging system (cds,cds_tags,tags) and i want to show the rows that have a specific list of tags submitted by user. Although i get the right results it shows only the tags that match the user's search tags.

```
SELECT cds.TITLE , GROUP_CONCAT( tags.TAG_NAME SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
FROM cds
JOIN cds_tags ON cds_tags.CD_ID = cds.ID
JOIN tags ON tags.TAG_ID = cds_tags.TAG_ID
WHERE tags.TAG_NAME IN ( *the tags the user searches for* )
GROUP BY cds.TITLE
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT tags.TAG_NAME ) = *the count of searching tags*
```

I want to get all the tags for for the cd and not only the ones the user searches for.

UPDATE: Although changing the WHERE clause to look for all cds.IDs that have the tags linked to them as proposed by linger fixed the problem in the first place and i can get all the tags for the cd, it doesn't get the results where ALL the tags are linked to a CD. 
e.g.  When I search for a CD with tags : rock , house .. i get all the CDs with 2 tags and AT LEAST 1 of the previous tags linked. is there a way to fix it?

UPDATE 2 : 
The problem was the **HAVING COUNT()** outside of the subquery. The right query is

```
SELECT cds.TITLE , GROUP_CONCAT( tags.TAG_NAME SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
FROM cds
  JOIN cds_tags ON cds_tags.CD_ID = cds.ID
  JOIN tags ON tags.TAG_ID = cds_tags.TAG_ID
WHERE cds.ID IN
(
  SELECT sct.CD_ID 
  FROM cds_tags sct
  JOIN tags st ON st.TAG_ID = sct.TAG_ID
  WHERE st.TAG_NAME IN ( *the tags the user searches for* )
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT tags.TAG_NAME ) = *the count of searching tags*
  GROUP BY sct.CD_ID

)
GROUP BY cds.TITLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing your WHERE clause to look for all `cds.ID`s that have the tags linked to them:

```
SELECT cds.TITLE , GROUP_CONCAT( tags.TAG_NAME SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
FROM cds
  JOIN cds_tags ON cds_tags.CD_ID = cds.ID
  JOIN tags ON tags.TAG_ID = cds_tags.TAG_ID
WHERE cds.ID IN
(
  SELECT sct.CD_ID 
  FROM cds_tags sct
    JOIN tags st ON st.TAG_ID = sct.TAG_ID
  WHERE st.TAG_NAME IN ( *the tags the user searches for* )
)
GROUP BY cds.TITLE
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT tags.TAG_NAME ) = *the count of searching tags*
```